# How to avoid duplicate calculations in automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I have this in my `LoanProfile`:

```
CreateMap<Loan, LoanDto>()
    .ForMember(
        dto => dto.TotalLoanAdvanced,
        loan => loan.MapFrom(l => l.TotalLoanAdvanced()))
    .ForMember(
        dto => dto.TotalInterestToLoanEndDate,
        loan => loan.MapFrom(l => l.InterestRepaymentAtLoanEndDate()))
    .ReverseMap()
    .AfterMap((dto, loan) =>
    {

    });
```

Where `TotalLoanAdvanced()` and `TotalinterestRepaymentToLoanEndDate()` are extension methods on `Loan`.

However, to calculate that total interest, my extension method is of course calling `TotalLoanAdvanced()` to multiply by the interest rate, meaning that I am calculaing `TotalLoanAdvanced` twice for each loan being mapped.

How can I avoid this?

I thought it might be doable with something like `BeforeMap` or `AfterMap`, but when I try

```
.AfterMap((dto, loan) =>
{
    dto.TotalLoanAdvanced = 5000000;
});
```

I can see that the `dto` is mapped as having a `TotalLoanAdvanced` of 0. Same things happens when doing that with `BeforeMap`:

```
.BeforeMap((loan, dto) =>
{
    dto.TotalLoanAdvanced = 5000000;
});
```

How should I be doing this?

Comment: Shouldn't it be in `BeforeMap`?

Comment: @Fabio I tried that as well but with the same results

Comment: Does having old classic map method without Automapper still an option for you?

Comment: Check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Understanding-your-mapping.html).

Answer (score 6):

I don't have an answer on how to fix the AutoMapper configuration. However, your question is *How can I avoid this?* and *How should I be doing this* so I want to answer with some advice: don't put business logic in your mapper configuration.

The reason not to do it are:

- Mapping objects should be kept as simple as possible, mapping properties by convention
- Don't add magic like this in the mapper configuration as it makes the code harder to understand/follow
- You'll avoid funky behavior like what you're having now
- Your code is harder to test

Comment: This, this, this and this!

Comment: Yes do NOT put business logic inside mappings please please please